# Expo-av Video not renderig on ios

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-av

I installed expo-av
and here is my code. It's working perfectly on android but not rendering on ios

```
     <Video
        style={{ height: height / 3, width }}
        source={{
          uri: "http://192.168.3.151:8000/videos/5YcCctaAhUpPBmUj9WmjwoVWlm2SiE8dCMjJatOw.mp4",
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        isLooping
        shouldPlay
      />
```

for the uri, it's retrieved from the database

Comment: You're missing a ref, e.g. const video = React.useRef(null); and then in your Video component: ref={video}

Comment: @RayPurchase you only need a ref if you want to control the video from another function